# Javascript cant find my function in a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to debug a function that returns a promise and for that I need a sleep function. I found this one:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

and it works when used outside of a promise. However when I want to use it in a promise, I get the error, that sleep was not found. This is my code:

```
async function f(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    await sleep(1000);

    /*
      rest of function
    */
  });
}
```

Comment: are they defined in the same file ? otherwise how do you export/import it ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli of course they are in the same file

Comment: Try to replace return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}) in function f with return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {}). I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: @ShivanshuGupta thanks thats working, can you write that as an answer so that I can close the question?

Comment: because you are using await, so it should always be used inside an async function. So here (resolve, reject) =>{} is acting as a parent function which is not async

Comment: For more info, you can follow this document: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}) in function f with return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {}). I hope it will solve your problem

```
async function f(filename) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await sleep(1000);

    /*
      rest of function
    */
  });
}
```

Comment: Except you shouldn't be using `await` inside a promise executor anyway.  By definition, you already have promises so you don't need to be wrapping it in another manually created promise.  That's an anti-pattern.  So, the whole premise of this question is flawed.  One shouldn't be making the promise executor `async`.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 0):

> However when I want to use it in a promise

You should [never create another promise inside the `new Promise` executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). Instead, call the `sleep` function inside the surrounding function `f` (which you already marked as `async`, presumably to use the `await` keyword):

```
async function f(filename) {
  await sleep(1000);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /* rest of function  */
  });
}
```

Your problem was also that the `(resolve, reject) => {…}` function is not `async`, so trying to use `await` inside there was a syntax error (in strict mode) and might also have caused the error message about the unexpected `sleep` token after the `await`.

Answer (score -1):

Hi try using below code add async in the return code because you are using await inside the return

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('inside sleep');
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  } 
   function f(filename) {
    return new Promise( async(resolve, reject) => {
      await sleep(7000);
      
      /*
        rest of function
      */
    });
  }
```